# Switching activities freeze animations

Tags: android, performance, kotlin

New to Android & Kotlin i'm trying to perform a simple transition between two activities.

So i have this two activities: SplashActivity & HomeActivity. 
The first that appears on screen is SplashActivity, i use it to download stuff, and i add some simple animations, just a layout rotating forever.

This is the animation :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false"  android:layout_height="10dp" 
android:layout_width="10dp">

<rotate
    android:duration="2500"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
</set>
```

Once everything is ready i simply change the activities like this (in my  SplashActivity) :

```
startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, HomeActivity::class.java))
finish()
```

Problem is that the rotate animation freeze while switching activies, and it looks awful, is there a way for me to perform a transition without the animation to freeze or it is just the way android works ? A simple smooth transition for a smooth developer :)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: i said Hi guys, but stack delete it i can see... So hi guys !